# how to create .bin file on external storage

Tags: android, file, external, bin

I used a lot of examples trying to understand why it doesnt create my file but i didn't and i need some help.

```
File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "FFFFFFFFF.bin");
try {
    myFile.createNewFile();
    setOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myFile));
        for (short i = 1; i <= this.array.length; i++) {
            this.array[i-1] = new myobject(i);
        }
        get_objOutputStream().writeObject(this.array);
        getOutputStream().close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the getters/setters are regular, it worked when i wrote it to internal file before i changed it a little so the problem is not an error or related to the array of my objects

thanks for any help

updates:

i got no errors, it just run and then i cant find the file when im looking for it when i plug my phone to my pc after installing and running.

and yes i did wrote the premition, that is not the problem

Comment: Can you post your error  ? It will be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add permission in manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```